# CakePHP Options: Not sure about this entry

Tags: php, serialization

I  have this in my options

```
a:4:{i:0;s:10:"Test";i:1;s:12:"FMy Files";i:2;s:7:"Walmen ";i:3;s:15:"Testing on the roof";}
```

How do I read or interpret it?

Does it floow have a certain criterion?

What is it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not JSON (notice the semicolons). This is [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) PHP data. You shouldn't have to do anything with it, and certainly not edit it (as you've obviously done, I guess to anonymise it): this is generated by PHP and should only be manipulated by the proper script. It contains metadata about itself, for data integrity checking, I think: Types and Lengths.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = json_decode($jsonEncodedString);
```

Update: After I read the code more closely, it seems, that this isn't JSON. This *may* be serialized PHP as @passcod already mentioned, but its broken. For example the segment `s:10:"Test"` describes a 10-characters String with content `Test`, that is obviously wrong. Simply `unserialize()` will fail. Dont know, where you get this from, but you should repair "the creator".

Comment: I don't believe this deserves a downvote. Downvote the question instead for being contradictory, not the answer!

Comment: @passcod: He wrote "json" in the title and also the "json"-tag is added. However, I didn't read the code that accurately, because I assumed the OP knows, what he is talking about, but you are right. I'll leave it for ... whatever reason ^^